# React native run Microsoft app locally without intune

Tags: react-native, authentication, emulation, simulator, intune

I am working on a mobile application for Microsoft built in React Native . This app uses Microsoft login for authentication. I was able to run the app fine in the emulator without enrolling the emulator to intune ( the computer is intune compliant ) . Suddenly Microsoft has mandated intune enrollment even for emulators , now I cannot login into the app on emulator .
I even tried to enroll the emulator to intune but it will simply ask me to "Reinstall company portal" in a loop . Also, iOS simulator doesn't allow intune installation . Please advise how I can continue development.

Answer (score 0):

*I even tried to enroll the emulator to intune but it will simply ask me to "Reinstall company portal" in a loop* - I suppose this could happen due to conditional access. Have you checked the sign-in logs what it says about conditional access? It looks like you guys are enforcing enrollment when it comes to native app

*Also, iOS simulator doesn't allow intune installation* - have you check if you can enroll the ios (not the emulator)? Also check the sign-in logs if it did failed just because the conditional access or it could be enrollment device platform restrictions

hope it helped